# double integral question involving volume

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

> Find the volume of the solid with height $h(x,y)=xy$ and base $D$, where $D$ is bounded by $y=x+2$ and $y=x^2$.

I believe this is a double integral question. I'm really not sure how to set up the bounds of this integral though, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$y$ values are from $x^2$ (bottom curve) to $x+2$ (top curve), and $x$ values are from $-1$ to $2$ (obtained by setting the two equal to each other), hence

$$\int_{-1}^2 \int^{x+2}_{x^2} xy dydx$$

The object will be below $z$ on the left of $y$-axis though. So if it is asking you to find the positive volume of both parts, you will need to separate it into two parts:

$$-\int_{-1}^0 \int^{x+2}_{x^2} xy dydx+\int_{0}^2 \int^{x+2}_{x^2} xy dydx$$

Answer (score 1):

1) Intersection points: $x^2-x-2=(x+1)(x-2)=0$ implies $x=-1$ or $x=2$.

2) since there is two intersection point, in this interval one of them is srictly bigger than the other. ($0+2>0^2$) We can eaisly see that $x+2>x^2$ on $(-1,2)$

3) Calculation:

$\int_{-1}^{2} \int_{x^2}^{x+2}xy \: dy \: dx= \int_{-1}^{2}[x(\frac{y^2}{2})_{y=x^2}^{y=x+2}]dx$. Now it is easy to calculate

Comment: exactly what i was looking for. thank you